# Javascript math.floor and math.random question

Tags: javascript

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var rnd = Math.random();
var rndK = letters[Math.floor(rnd*letters.length)];
return rndK;
```

My question to this is, I've run it a couple of times and it prints D sometimes, but I don't really understand why, since to my knowledge,

```
math.random() returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1 but not 1,
math.floor() returns the highest integer that's less or equal to the value, rounding down essentially.
```

shouldn't D only be printed out when the rnd gives a 1, but since math.floor() rounds down, this shouldn't be possible?
I'm probably missing something really obvious here, thanks if anyone can explain it for a complete beginner to javascript.

Comment: D is at index 3 not 4

Comment: ahhh, okay, so its because javascript essentially counts from 0 as 1? so that A=0 and D=3?
thank you very much

Comment: As mentioned above. Arrays in JS are zero indexed. The max possible number of `Math.random()*letters.length` is `3.96` (`0.99*4`). Floor that to get 3 and that's why you see `D`

Comment: @CarlMarkham `Math.random()` can return numbers higher than 0.99 (as long as they're smaller than 1).

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `math.random()` only returns a value between 0 and 1. Multiplying it by `letters.length`, which is 4, and flooring it will only return a value between 0 and 3, never 4. That will still return D sometimes, because the index of D is 3. Remember, the index of the element is the element's place minus 1. So the index of A is 0, the index of B is 1, the index of C is 2, and the index of D is 3. If you don't want D returned, multiply `math.random()` by `letters.length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Math.floor(rnd*letters.length)
```

Returns a number between 0 and 3 in your case. Because `letters.length === 4`

`letters[0] === "A"`

`letters[3] === "D"`

So everything works as expected :)